# Trying to call variable in C after if statement

Tags: c

I'm making a calculator application, and I wanna see if I can call a variable I set in an if statement; after the if statement has ended. Can I do it? I've tried a couple of things but I just can't get it to work.

```
int main()
{
    // ...
    int finished;
    do{
        // ...           
        if(operator == 1){
            int finished = number[1] + number[2];
            printf("\n\n%d \+ %d is: %d", number[1], number[2], finished);

        }
        if(operator == 2){
            int finished = number[1] - number[2];
            printf("\n\n%d \- %d is: %d", number[1], number[2], finished);

        }
        // ...
        printf("\ndebug %d\n: ", finished);
        // ...
    } while (doAgain == 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which line are you referring to?

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Oooh I'm so sorry. at the very end of the code, the int variable finished. When it asks if you want to continue. I wanna reuse the contents of the finished variable as number[1].

Comment: @Mihai Maruseac Your edit removed the initial declaration of `finished` so made substantial alterations to the question.  I've rolled it back.

Comment: @simonc: thanks, I overlooked that definition. I've updated the edit :)

Comment: @Austen Some suggestions: Transform your series of if in a [case switch](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson5.html). As default value (operator is no one of those handled) you will set a variable `resultComputed`, previously initialized at `true`, as `false`. You can also print a warning message in this case. You can put then printf *after* you have computed `finished`, so that you can put it only one time. And you call `printf` only if `resultComputed` is `true`.

Comment: @MihaiMaruseac Your edits removed the use of `finished` and thus obscured the point of the question.

Comment: The uses are there. The ones relevant to the question.

Comment: @MihaiMaruseac No, the whole point is the access of `finished` after the loop exits.

Comment: No, after the if branches. Which is there in the edit.

Comment: There is no `finished` access after the end of the `do` loop.

Comment: Before do-while() int finished is defined as integer; now there is no need to define the same variable "finished" again & again in the code.

Answer (score 5):

No, the scope of a variable is up to the end of the nextmost `{ }` pair.

If you need to access it here, you should define `int finished;` at the top (what you already do).

So just replace `int finished = ...` with `finished = ...`. This just writes the pre-existing variable instead of defining a new one.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot access a variable after it has fallen out of scope.

You'll need to add a new variable:

```
int fin;

if (...) {
    int finished;
    fin = finished;
}

fin; // still accessible. but finished no longer exists.
```

**Or** remove the declarations from the inner variable so the higher-scoped one is used:

```
int finished;

if (...) {
    finished = ...;
}

finished; // still accessible, of course.
```

Comment: Read the code again. The OP already has a `finished` variable outside the loop. s/he needs to get rid of the local declarations of `finished` that hide the outer one.

Comment: I learned that from the other answers. It seemed disingenuous (and unnecessary) to add it to mine.

Comment: SO isn't some sort of ego game, it's about good answers ... `fin` doesn't make for one. I suggest that you just delete your answer, since you have nothing to add.

Comment: I have edited. I really think I do not deserve the "ego" remark.

Comment: But's that's exactly what you're referring to with talk of "disingenuous" ... SO answers properly have nothing to do with such personal matters. If you were offended by it, you misunderstood what I was saying.

Comment: What I meant was that you don't need to feel guilty about including in your answer things that you learned from other answers, and if it bothered you to duplicate other answers, then the logical thing is to just delete it.

Answer (score 2):

In C and almost all programming languages there are two things which are related to variables: the domain of visibility (scope) and the domain of life. Your question covers the first one.

In C, the rules are simple:

- global variables are visible everywhere in the current compilation unit
- local variables are visible only in the enclosing `{`..`}` scope

In your case, you must not redefine the `finished` in the `if` branches.